# Carrierwave_direct: How to upload asset and associate it with a future object (object not created yet)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I want to be able to use [Carrierwave-Direct](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct) to upload assets in the background using resque/sidekiq. I checked out the http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3 railscast but there are a few things that are different in the app that I am working on. Unfortunately the assets are part of an object that is not being saved upon the asset uploading.

Is there a way to associate the uploaded asset to a specific part of a form so that when the form is submitted that specific object is associated to it?